# Datadog Java APIs for alerting

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle, datadog

I am new to Datadog and I am trying to implement mute/unmute functions from Datadog on my AWS cloud stack. I want to do that using AWS Lambda Functions. I am looking for a java based solution. Is there any Java based sdk provided for the same?

I found out that Datadog provides APIs to schedule downtime [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=python#downtimes)

but the support I can see is either Python, Ruby or Curl. How can I construct a Java based solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has support to CURL means you can make REST API calls. Try using some Http libraries like **HttpURLConnection** in java to make those POST requests.

I don't think we need a java based SDK for that as you can frame your own SDK on top of REST api's.